# Use GeoDjango to split an existing polyline based on road length and road completion percentage

Tags: geodjango, django

How can I use GeoDjango to split an existing Farm-to-Road Market Proposal- polyline based on road length and user-inputted road completion percentage?

I have a sample Farm-to-Road Market Proposal. The idea is to split it (polyline) since road completion is segmented due to budget constraint.

[image]